# How to reduce a data frame into single row with vectors

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, reduce

I have this DF

```
  email       date      user_ipaddress       other data    
1 x@bla.com 2020-03-24  177.95.75.230         xxxx
2 x@bla.com 2020-04-02  177.139.49.93         yyyy
3 x@bla.com 2020-04-02  177.139.49.93         zzzz
```

and I want to transform this data to the shape it is going to be stored

the whole problem would be a big data frame with distinct emails and I want to reduce all data for each email in a single row like so

```
  email       date      user_ipaddress                       other data    
1 x@bla.com 2020-04-02  c('177.95.75.230','177.139.49.93')   c('xxxx','yyyy','zzzz')
```

actually, if someone could help me only with the case that there is only one email address it would save my life but feel free to help with the whole problem

using

```
ipadreessVec<-Reduce(append,x =df$network_userid)
```

I can get my vector `c('177.95.75.230','177.139.49.93')`  but if i try to make

```
newdf$network_userid<-a
```

I get

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, network_userid, value = c("20562206-f557-48a3-861b-5d1e18524bbb",  : 
  replacement has 3 rows, data has 1
```

any answer that makes me go a step further will get a approve even if it does not solve everything.

Comment: i'm not sure  it this is not a very hard problem cuz  i got like 4 brilliant answers in less then a hour!.. or maybe it people that had it before  suffered so much that they will remember forever how to solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a `list` column grouped by 'email', 'date'

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% 
    group_by(email, date) %>%
    summarise_all(list)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   email [1]
#  email     date       user_ipaddress otherdata
#  <chr>     <chr>      <list>         <list>   
#1 x@bla.com 2020-03-24 <chr [1]>      <chr [1]>
#2 x@bla.com 2020-04-02 <chr [2]>      <chr [2]>
```

---

Or in the `devel` version use `across` with `summarise`

```
DF %>%
   group_by(email, date) %>% 
   summarise(across(everything(), list))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   email [1]
#  email     date       user_ipaddress otherdata
#  <chr>     <chr>      <list>         <list>   
#1 x@bla.com 2020-03-24 <chr [1]>      <chr [1]>
#2 x@bla.com 2020-04-02 <chr [2]>      <chr [2]>
```

#### data

```
DF <- structure(list(email = c("x@bla.com", "x@bla.com", "x@bla.com"
), date = c("2020-03-24", "2020-04-02", "2020-04-02"),
 user_ipaddress = c("177.95.75.230", 
"177.139.49.93", "177.139.49.93"),
otherdata = c("xxxx", "yyyy", 
"zzzz")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```

Comment: > DF %>%
+     group_by(email, date) %>% 
+     summarise(across(everything(), list))
Error in across(everything(), list) : could not find function "across"
> DF %>% 
+     group_by(email, date) %>%
+     summarise_all(list)
Error: expecting a one sided formula, a function, or a function name.
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

Comment: @filscapo it is in devel versoin

Comment: @filscapo what is the issue with `summarise_all`

Answer (score 3):

I might be misunderstanding you, and it seems more likely that you want something like @akrun shows, but interpreting you literally, you might want something using `dput`:

```r
as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) capture.output(dput(unique(x)))))
#>         email                          date                      user_ipaddress
#> 1 "x@bla.com" c("2020-03-24", "2020-04-02") c("177.95.75.230", "177.139.49.93")
#>                       other
#> 1 c("xxxx", "yyyy", "zzzz")
```

Comment: this is flawless

Answer (score 3):

```
library('data.table')
```

**by email and date:**

```
setDT(df)[, .(user_ipaddress = paste0(user_ipaddress, collapse = ","),
              other = paste0(other_data, collapse = ",")), by = .(email, date)]

#       email       date              user_ipaddress     other
# 1: x@bla.com 2020-03-24               177.95.75.230      xxxx
# 2: x@bla.com 2020-04-02 177.139.49.93,177.139.49.93 yyyy,zzzz
```

**by email only:**

```
setDT(df)[, .(date = paste0(date, collapse = ","),
              user_ipaddress = paste0(user_ipaddress, collapse = ","),
              other = paste0(other_data, collapse = ",")), by = .(email)]

#        email                             date                            user_ipaddress          other
# 1: x@bla.com 2020-03-24,2020-04-02,2020-04-02 177.95.75.230,177.139.49.93,177.139.49.93 xxxx,yyyy,zzzz
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text='email       date      user_ipaddress       other_data    
1 x@bla.com 2020-03-24  177.95.75.230         xxxx
                 2 x@bla.com 2020-04-02  177.139.49.93         yyyy
                 3 x@bla.com 2020-04-02  177.139.49.93         zzzz', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `aggregate` in base R:

```
dfout <- aggregate(.~email,df,FUN = function(x) list(unique(levels(x))))
```

such that

```
> dfout
      email                   date               user_ipaddress       other data
1 x@bla.com 2020-03-24, 2020-04-02 177.139.49.93, 177.95.75.230 xxxx, yyyy, zzzz
```

**DATA**

```
df <-  structure(list(email = c("x@bla.com", "x@bla.com", "x@bla.com"
), date = c("2020-03-24", "2020-04-02", "2020-04-02"), user_ipaddress = c("177.95.75.230", 
"177.139.49.93", "177.139.49.93"), `other data` = c("xxxx", "yyyy", 
"zzzz")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```